# How to test a controller that has a @Mixin of a Basecontroller

Tags: grails, spock

I've created a BaseController that I mixinto other Controllers.

Example:

```
class BaseController () {
  def somemethod () {
    return "some method"
  }
}

@Mixin(BaseController)

class MyController {
   def getsomething() {
     def test = somemethod()
     return test
   }
}
```

I'm trying to write a test case for `MyController` however, it fails because it can't find `somemethod`.

My test currently looks like this

```
@TestFor(MyController)
class MyControllerSpec extends Specification {
  def "test getsomething" () {
    when:
      def m = controller.getsomething()
    then:
      response.contentAsString == "some method"
  }
}
```

But I keep getting errors like these:

```
No signature of method: somemethod() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

**Question**

How can I write spock test for `MyController` so that it finds `somemethod` as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does using `@TestMixin(BaseController)` in the Spock test for `MyController` work?
Ans:- No, it is not required.

**UPDATE**
There is a small modification required in `MyController`. Use `render` instead of `return`. Here is the detail:

```
class BaseController {
    def someMethod() { 
        "Some Method"
    }
}

import grails.util.Mixin
//Remember to use Grails @Mixin instead of Groovy @Mixin
@Mixin(BaseController)
class MyController {
    def getSomething() {
        def test = someMethod()
        render test
    }
}

//Unit Test
@TestFor(MyController)
class MyControllerUnitSpec extends Specification {
    void "test get something"() {
        when:
            controller.getSomething()
        then:
            response.contentAsString == "Some Method"
    }
}

//Controller Integration Test
import grails.plugin.spock.ControllerSpec
class MyControllerIntSpec extends ControllerSpec {
    void "test get something integration"() {
        when:
            controller.getSomething()
        then:
            controller.response.contentAsString == "Some Method"
    }
}
```

**Notes:-**
I found some difficulties while testing which are listed below:-

- The above tests passed with an initial run. But, when I changed `render` to `return` just to see my tests failing, I got compilation errors because of the Grails `@Mixin` I used in `MyController` (two version of `withFormat`). Sometimes I think it does not play well. Changing the mixin to Groovy `@Mixin` everything went good. I did not like that. I had to stick to Grails `@Mixin`. Apparently and surprisingly, doing a `grails clean && grails compile` eradicated the issue. I was able to use Grails @Mixin properly. I am still looking at this discrepancy.
- If the above problem were persistent, I would have thought of adding runtime mixin in the `setup()` method in unit test.

Like

```
def setup(){
    //I would not like to do the same in Integration test
    //Integration test should do it for me atleast. 
    MyController.mixin BaseController
}
```

- I used `ControllerSpec` instead of `IntegrationSpec` in integration test. Seems like injection and convention is maintained better in `ControllerSpec` for controllers. If you see, nowhere am I instantiating `MyContoller` in the int test.
- I have not tested it in normal Junit's Unit and Integration tests, they should be good as well.

Comment: It doesn't :( I've tried `@TestMixin` and also `@Mixin` in spock test for `MyController`

Comment: I am not sure whether we can use `TestFor` and `TestMixin` in this case. I will test and let you know.

Comment: I'm already utilizing `TestFor` and it doesn't take more than one argument either

Comment: @Anthony See my update in answer. `@TestFor` is only meant for one argument; controller or service or domain or a simple class. Have a look at [Test Mixins](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/testing.html)

Answer (score 3):

My strong advice is to **not use mixins in Grails at all**. It generates faulty bahvior in tests. Also you need an extra code to apply these mixins for tests, which is bad.

For further information read this replay: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/grails-2-2-2-upgrade-from-2-2-0-breaks-mixin-on-controller-tp4645461p4645466.html, which applies to mixins in Grails in general, or take look of many issues reported in comments of this issue: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8652 (classes lose their mixins during unit tests).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answers in this thread, http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Testing-a-controller-that-has-a-Mixin-td4645595.html

I ended up using,

```
void setup() {
    MyController.mixin(BaseController)
}
```